# Grouping similar data to maximize intra-group correlation and minimize inter-group correlation

Tags: r, time-series, classification, cluster-analysis, correlation

so this is my problem.
I have daily return data of 2000 stocks, and below is a small sample of it
(s1 to s8, day1 to day15)

I'll call my data "df".

```
> df[1:15,1:8]
          s1        s2         s3         s4        s5        s6        s7        s8
1  -0.026410 -0.001030 -0.0027660  0.0126500 -0.030110  0.001476 -0.008271 -0.005299
2  -0.018990 -0.013680 -0.0092050 -0.0008402 -0.002739 -0.014170 -0.006091 -0.011920
3   0.004874  0.024140 -0.0002107 -0.0084770 -0.006825 -0.001448 -0.002724 -0.003132
4   0.019300 -0.004649  0.0223400  0.0080200 -0.008197 -0.015270  0.004064 -0.008149
5   0.010350 -0.010650  0.0087780  0.0059960 -0.001390 -0.006454  0.018990  0.002822
6   0.028650  0.010490  0.0157200 -0.0004123  0.019750 -0.005902  0.004261  0.019110
7   0.004203 -0.002682 -0.0099840 -0.0070060 -0.025670 -0.014550 -0.016700 -0.011580
8  -0.042170 -0.019490 -0.0023140 -0.0083030 -0.018170  0.021160 -0.006864 -0.009438
9   0.017250  0.026600  0.0031630 -0.0069090  0.035990  0.008429  0.001500 -0.011830
10 -0.037400 -0.022370  0.0088460  0.0012690 -0.050820 -0.025300 -0.028040 -0.023790
11 -0.091140 -0.018830  0.0052160 -0.0403000  0.001410 -0.007050 -0.024340 -0.013110
12 -0.051620  0.004791  0.0336000 -0.0094320 -0.018320 -0.019490 -0.044080 -0.024020
13  0.007711  0.002158 -0.0177400  0.0090470 -0.004346 -0.001562 -0.096030  0.015840
14  0.041440 -0.001072 -0.0168400  0.0180300 -0.012980 -0.015280  0.059780  0.014730
15 -0.042620 -0.025560 -0.0180200 -0.0115200  0.033320 -0.015150 -0.014580 -0.012710
```

**I need a way to group them so that the intra-group correlation is maximized and inter-group correlation is minimized.**

So for example, I can group them into **two groups** randomly as following:
(s1, s2, s3, s4) and (s5, s6, s7, s8)
The problem is, some of the stocks might be correlated with each other, and some might not.

So my solution was to:

get a correlation matrix (assuming Pearson's method works fine)

```
cor_df <- cor(df)
```

melt(flatten) the correlation list in descending order and remove duplicates and rows with correlation coefficient = 1 (used reshape library)

```
cor_df_melt <- melt(cor_df)
names(cor_df_melt)[1] <- "x1"
names(cor_df_melt)[2] <- "x2"
names(cor_df_melt)[3] <- "corr"
cor_df_ordered <- cor_df_melt[order(-cor_df_sample_melt["corr"]),]
```

Then I numbered the flattened matrix, removed duplicates(even numbered ones) and rows with correlation coefficient = 1

```
cor_df_numbered <- cbind(row=c(1:nrow(cor_df_ordered)),cor_df_ordered)
cor_df_ready <- cor_df_numbered[cor_df_numbered$row%%2==0&cor_df_numbered$corr%%2!=1,2:4]
```

After this, my data frame with nicely ordered correlation coefficients for each pair in descending order was ready as follows:

```
> cor_df_ready
   x1 x2       corr
63 s7 s8 0.49223783
57 s1 s8 0.42518667
50 s2 s7 0.42369762
49 s1 s7 0.40824283
58 s2 s8 0.40395569
42 s2 s6 0.40394894
54 s6 s7 0.39408677
62 s6 s8 0.38536734
34 s2 s5 0.36882709
53 s5 s7 0.36066870
45 s5 s6 0.35734278
59 s3 s8 0.34295713
51 s3 s7 0.34163733
61 s5 s8 0.33264868
9  s1 s2 0.32812763
41 s1 s6 0.31221715
18 s2 s3 0.30692909
43 s3 s6 0.29390325
33 s1 s5 0.28845243
35 s3 s5 0.27859972
17 s1 s3 0.25039209
52 s4 s7 0.12989487
60 s4 s8 0.12095196
25 s1 s4 0.10902471
26 s2 s4 0.09471694
44 s4 s6 0.08039435
36 s4 s5 0.06957264
27 s3 s4 0.06027389
```

(btw i have no idea why the row number is disordered like that... can anyone explain?)

From here, my intuition was for the top pair with the highest correlation coefficient 0.49223783 (s7, s8), they had to be in the same group.

So from my cor_df_ready data frame, I chose all pairs with "s7" included and extracted the 4 stocks that appear at the top of the list (s7, s8, s2, s1) and named them group 1.

I then excluded all rows including (s7, s8, s2, s1) from my cor_df_ready, and repeated the process to come up with the second group (s3, s4, s5, s6).

well in this example I didn't have to repeat the process as there was only one last set remaining.

Then, I got the correlation matrix for each group and added the sum of every correlation coefficient:

```
group1_cor <- cor(group1)
group2_cor <- cor(group2)

cor_sum <- sum(group1_cor) + sum(group2_cor)
```

then I got the mean of each row in each group, and calculated the sum of the correlation matrix for the two group means, and named it cor_sum_mean.

Lastly, I calculated for: cor_sum_mean/cor_sum

The intuition was, maximized correlation within group would maximize cor_sum where the minimized correlation between groups would also minimize cor_sum_mean.

I want to get as big cor_sum as possible(intra-group correlation) and as small cor_sum_mean as possible(intra-group correlation).

Using my method for the whole data, I divided 2000 stocks into 10 groups and what I got was

```
#cor_sum = 131923.1
#cor_sum_mean = 83.1731
#cor_sum_mean/cor_sum = 0.0006305
```

I KNOW I can get the cor_sum_mean/cor_sum down to 0.000542 (or even smaller), but I am simply stuck.

I searched google, stackoverflow, crossvalidated, and I was getting the idea that machine learning/time series clustering/classification could be the answer that I'm looking for.

The following two pre-posted questions seemed helpful, but I'm only starting to learn data science so I'm having a hard time understanding them....

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9475/time-series-clustering/19042#19042

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3238/time-series-clustering-in-r

Can anyone please explain or direct me what to look for in specific?

This was a long question... Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0):

Use hierarchical clustering.

With average linkage, you optimize the average correlation.